# Why in Chrome browser being launched by Selenium via a secured vpn, an application is not getting loaded properly?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Why in a Chrome browser being launched by Selenium via a secured vpn, an application is not getting loaded properly,whereas the same application when being launched manually by the same chrome browser is getting launched properly?

Comment: are you usuing local or remote selenium driver? and is selenium using different browser profile than what you manually use?

Comment: Hi, it's the local selenium driver we are using. No its the same Chrome browser that we are using manually.

Comment: my question was: is it the same or different **Chrome profile**? If you don't specify explicitly, Selenium will create a new profile one each execution. While when you are using browser manually, you will use the same profile every time you launch Chrome. Your manual profile could have some settings that Selenium profile doesn't have. This  is the most likely reason for difference you are observing.

Comment: It is the same Chrome profile that i am using for both manual and automation testing